# Implementing interface correctly in C# BOL classes

Tags: c#, .net

I've been searching for a bit and found similar things but nothing that quite answers my question. Here it is- I have two classes. A, B. I want class C to have all the properites of those two classes. This is in the Object Layer, c#.net.

Class A:

```
public class A
{
  public string property1 { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
  public string anotherproperty { get; set; }
}

public interface IB
{
  B b { get; set; }
}

public class C : A, IB
{
  //nothing here cause hopefully it inherits everything
}
```

I have no idea if my implementation is even close. I do get error message of "C does not implement interface member IB"

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have two classes. A, B. I want class C to have all the properites of those two classes.

...then you will have to manually add either A's or B's properties to C. C# does not support multiple inheritance, sorry.

---

However, in most cases multiple inheritance is not needed. A common alternative is to use *composition instead of inheritance*: For example, you could have your class C provide references to instances of A and B:

```
public class C
{
    private A a = new A();
    private B b = new B();

    public A A { get { return a; } }
    public B B { get { return b; } }
}
```

This would allow you to access all properties via `myC.A.property1` and `myC.B.anotherproperty`.

If you really need to combine *implementations* from both `A` and `B`  in `C`, you might need to have a look at [Mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) libraries for C#.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
    public class ClassA
    {
        public string AProp { get { return "AProp";} }
    }

    public class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        public string BProp { get { return "BProp"; } }
    }

    public class ClassC : ClassB
    {

    }
```

And then:

```
ClassC c = new ClassC();
Console.WriteLine(c.AProp);
Console.WriteLine(c.BProp);
```

Prints:

> AProp
>
> BProp

You can't override anything but you can access the inherited properties.